# On a windows machine, how can I get my virtual environments to matchup on powershell and on bash/zsh?

Tags: python, windows, bash, powershell, virtualenv

I'm having an issue with my environment setup on windows10. Using pycharm I have created a a new project, and as part of that I have created a new virtualenv for use in this. I select my base interpreter to be python3.11 By default the terminal on pycharm on a windows is powershell and once this is setup it automatically activates the environment.

To check this is matched up I have the following script:

> import sys
> print(sys.version)

which outputs:

> 3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]

For both running it in IDE and also running it from terminal (with `python main.py`).
And when I run

> Get-Command python | fl *

On the powershell terminal it informs me that the python executable being ran is at the following location:

> C:\Users---- \ -----\My Documents\projects\ --- \env/Scripts\python.exe

And it also confirm that this is python version 3.11 (more specifically 3.11.4150.1013).

After some testing of installing packages etc I can see the interpreter is the same instance of python as on powershell. However I am not a powershell fan at all and want to use bash. So on bash I navigate to the project folder and run

> source env/Scripts/activate

which activates the environment on the bash terminal, I then run

> python --version

to confirm it is the same version of python, however it isn't and is outputting `python 3.10.6`. I check the pyvenv.cfg file and that suggests that the version of python should be 3.11.4.

Why is this not activating the same environment? And what can I do to keep all the environments in sync?

Comment: which bash are you using ? wsl ? cygwin ? gitbash ? other ?

Comment: GNU bash, version 5.1.16. Its just the default that loads when running `bash` on powershell